# Choosing the right hardware for an interactive kiosk - screen

Tags: touchscreen, point-of-sale

My goal is to develop an interactive kiosk with only touchscreen available to visitors for a local museum. I must admit that I'm a freshman in this part of hardware world, but I really like the sound of this challenge, so I need to get some info/advice first about kiosk's components.

Regarding to the software part, I'm going to use an Arch Linux OS and develop my own kiosk software for the most minimalistic framework possible. I opt for making an app based on WebGL (because I believe this is my forte), so WebGL Hardware Acceleration must be supported by GPU. In case WebGL would be too heavy, my emergency plan is to build a good HTML site or a standalone Java app (which could be the hardest way, but more efficient).

So now about the hardware: 
The first thing that interests me the most are touchscreens - is there a special type of them, i.e. industrial ones, that are appropriate for this purpose? Where to find them and which one would you recommend me?

The computer is covered here [Choosing the right hardware for an interactive kiosk - computer](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/382/choosing-the-right-hardware-for-an-interactive-kiosk-computer)

Comment: There is no problem with the question and is completely on-topic here.

It asks about a computer which can be compatible with the given details. So, there's nothing wrong about it, and the question is not broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are industrial grade touchscreens built exactly for this purpose. I can recommend [something in this family](https://www.icpdas-usa.com/touch_panel_monitors.html). Or you can start your own search on big industrial supplier's sites like [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/human-machine-interface-hmi/946?s=N4IgTCBcDaIC4HsCuBjAFgZxQJwKa4DsACEAXQF8g) or [Allied Electronics](https://www.alliedelec.com/plcs-hmis/hmi-displays/).